# how to set default value of form_for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, form-for

I would like to know how to set default value on form_for select.

My code goes like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 .
 .
 .

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.select(:user_group_id, options_for_select(@user_groups.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },   "Select Category")) %>
 </div>
<%= end %>
```

Obviously it would return all the values of the field user_group. On my edit page, I would like to set the default value to whatever value the user have in the user_group. Pls help

Comment: Your code example isn't showing up.  If you fix that, your question will probably be answered fairly quickly...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass a second option to `options_for_select` that indicates the selected *value*.

```
options_for_select(@user_groups.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, @user.user_group)
```

Obviously I'm not sure how your models are set up, but if necessary you use a method like [find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001484) to locate the entry you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter :selected =>

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
     .
     .
     .

     <div class="field">
     <%= f.select(:user_group_id, options_for_select(@user_groups.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },   "Select Category"), :selected =>f.object.user_group_id) %>
     </div>
    <%= end %>
```