# Preselect value dynamically in a select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following select for an associated object instance:

`<%= f.select :shop_id, Shop.all.map {|shop| [shop.name, shop.id]} %>`

I want to preselect one of the option values dynamically, i.e. different from time to time.

I've tried what is given in other so-answers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216513/1417223) but nothing is happening.

How do I preselect an option value, off of an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `options_from_collection_for_select` which allow you to specify which option to select

Documentation: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select

In this example, the `Shop` with id 17 will be selected:

```
<%= f.select :shop_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Shop.all, :id, :name, 17) %>
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work, could it be that it isn't a select_tag, but an object instance on an association (f.select)? Or are they supposed to work identically?

Comment: It is made to work with form builder, the snippet I pasted is the correct way to do it.

Comment: The 17 is an example, I assume you did not just copy/paste my snippet, and you adapted it right? And what do you mean by 'it does not work'?

Comment: Of course you're right (and of course I didn't use your ID...), I was just foolish enough to only refresh the webpage and not requesting a brand new page (even though I don't get how it can differ). 
Thanks for your excellent help!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a form_for, so just set up the value in controller, It doesn't need to modify the view.

```
   def new
     @your_model = YourModel.new(shop_id: 10)
   end
```

Comment: Yes that would have been n option if it wasn't that I really want it to show up in the view...

Comment: I don't understand it clearly. @BenjaminSinclaire 's answer should work too.

Comment: I now understand your solution, and it is excellent. The form helper got unreadable with a conditional inside of it. I actually went with the controller way :) But as my question was so explicit about the form_helper I checked the other answer as the accepted one. Thanks a lot for your time!!