# Rails how to set default selected value for form_for w/ content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a select form in Rails form_for like below:

```
<%= f.select :language_id, f, :selected => 2 do %>
  <% [['English', 1], ['Japanese', 2]].each do |c| -%>
    <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But this does not set the second option (Japanese) as the default.

Does anyone know how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using content_tag for a reason?  There are easier ways...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216513/4664553), I think it would be helpful for you

```
options_for_select(@user_groups.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, @user.user_group)
```